# How do I move an element to the middle of a bootstrap row?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

With my current code, the "test" paragraph is spanning the entire page. I would like the width to wrap the text, `(width:auto)`, however that's not working. This element is meant to be a button in the center of the page. I'm using the Bootstrap 3.0 Grid system, by the way.

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="container-fluid" id="FullContainer">
    <!-- Cover Page -->
    <div class="row" id="CoverPageRow"> 
        <div class="col-xs-12", id="HeaderText"> Mastery Wireframe </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12", id="SubHeaderText"> Become a master at what you do. </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12", id="DiscoverMoreButton"> <p id="test"> Discover More </p></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.col-md-12 {
    height: auto;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 200%;
}

#test {
    background-color: blue;
    border: 1px white solid;
    width: auto;
}
```

So how do I get the width to set to auto, so that this button doesn't span the entire page?

Comment: Syntax note - don't use commas to separate attributes in an element (`<div class="col-xs-12", id="HeaderText">` should be `<div class="col-xs-12" id="HeaderText">`)

Answer (score 1):

`<p>` tags are block level by default.  If you make it `inline-block` and then set it's parent to `text-align: center` it should work.  Note that you won't need `width: auto`.

```
#DiscoverMoreButton {
  text-align: center;
}

#test {
  background-color: blue;
  border: 1px white solid;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsbin.com/nalin/1/edit)**

---

Note that `col-xs-12` means be 100% wide.  As such, it's not really needed here as `<div>` is 100% wide by default.

So you could slim everything down, and use some of Bootstraps helper and button classes to center and style the btn (`.text-center` and `btn btn-primary`).

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="FullContainer">
  <!-- Cover Page -->
  <div id="CoverPageRow"> 
    <div id="HeaderText">Mastery Wireframe</div>
      <div id="SubHeaderText">Become a master at what you do.</div>
      <div class="text-center">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Discover more</a>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**[Demo 2](http://jsbin.com/nalin/2/edit)**

Comment: Ah I see, thanks! I think I'm going to go with the above button solution, once I can figure out how to center that. Just because it's a bootstrap button instead of a custom-made div button.

Comment: Tecnhically, as you've only specified `col-xs-12` classes, you don't need any of the bootstrap grid classes (including the row), because col-xs-12 means 'be 100%' wide, which is what a `<div>` is by default.  So you could slim everything down to this: http://jsbin.com/nalin/2/edit

Comment: I love this solution, this way my button doesn't scale down as the page scales, so I keep all the text in my button. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Probably a better idea to remove the paragraph tag and use an offset class to center your button.  See docs here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/

```
<div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4">Button text here</div>
```

Also, any reason why you're not using the btn classes for buttons instead?

Comment: I'm new to bootstrap, didn't know about  'button' haha thanks for that. And I can get offset to move my button over, but it never gets centered between offset-5 and offset-6. How do I get it to center?

Comment: In order to center it, you'll have to give it a span of at least 2.  Bootstrap gives you 12 grid boxes, so you could do a div with a minimum of 2 columns and still be centered: <div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-2"></div>.

Comment: Replace your <div class="col-xs-12", id="DiscoverMoreButton"> <p id="test"> Discover More </p></div>  with <div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-5" id="DiscoverMoreButton">Discover More</div>

Answer (score 0):

The really quick answer is use `.text-center`

Example:

```
<div class="row text-center">
  <div class="col">
    <p>Some centered content here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```